# How to get values from Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, button, ckeditor

I done **multiple ckeditor's** and buttons dynamically when clicking on button `add()`. Clicking on button `add()` creating ckeditor. If  want to type some text in editor -> click on `save()` button it will likely display to console atleast. Tried many ways but errors. Full codes below :

**Html**

`<button type="button" class="add" (click)="add()">Add Page</button>`

**add( )**

`var el = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<divcontenteditable="true">SomeText</div>' );
CKEDITOR.document.getBody().append( el );
CKEDITOR.replace(el);`

`var btn3 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var d3 = document.createTextNode("Save");
 btn3.onclick = function(){
 console.log(CKEDITOR.instances.el.getData(););`

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

I done little changes :

`this.htmlContent = '<div id="mainId"></div>';
 this.el = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<div id="mainId"></div>' );
 CKEDITOR.document.getBody().append(this.el);
 CKEDITOR.replace(this.el);`

`var btn3 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var d3 = document.createTextNode("Save");
 btn3.onclick = function(){
 console.log(CKEDITOR.instances["mainId"].getData(););`

Try this out